# extracting data

Tags: android, jquery, html

i want to extract data from a website the data structure like this

```
<td  class="text-anouncments"><span class="nav-white"><marquee onmouseover=this.stop() onmouseout=this.start() behavior="scroll"  width="100%"  direction="left" scrollamount="3" scrolldelay="3"  ><strong>
                    <a href="index.php?name=News&file=article&topic=3&sid=1510" class="nav-white">Title</a></strong> , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>
                    <a href="index.php?name=News&file=article&topic=3&sid=1508" class="nav-white">Title </a></strong> , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>
                    <a href="index.php?name=News&file=article&topic=3&sid=1502" class="nav-white">Title</a></strong> , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>
                    <a href="index.php?name=News&file=article&topic=3&sid=1501" class="nav-white">Title</a></strong> , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>
                    <a href="index.php?name=News&file=article&topic=3&sid=1497" class="nav-white">Title</a></strong> , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</marquee></span></td>
```

my question is can i get the linked Title between the `<a></a>` tag put them in a list to build an android web-application

Answer (score 0):

With the sample code below you can get the text between the `<a>` tags , which at your example is `Title`

If you want the actual link of each one then it is stored at the `link` variable, which at your example is `index.php?name=News&file=article&topic=3&sid=1510` etc.

```
$('.nav-white').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text(); //the text between the <a> tags
  var link = $(this).attr('href'); //the link that each one points to
  //print them to the console just to see that it actually works
  console.log(txt);
  console.log(link );
});
```

You can make the `txt` and `link` variables arrays so you can use them in another function if you wish.

```
var texts = new Array();
var links = new Array();

$('.nav-white').each(function() {
  texts.push( $(this).text() ); //the text between the <a> tags
  links.push( $(this).attr('href') ); //the link that each one points to
});
```

Also you have typed wrong the `strong` attribute. It is `<strong>`some text`</strong>` . In the code you posted you have it reversed.